# Grubs manual installation on windows

Tags: bootloader

Should I install a boot loader before I install Ubuntu? If so, how can I install it manually from windows 7?

Comment: Are you planning to replace Windows or dual-boot?  If dual-booting, grub 2 will become the boot loader and you will be able to choose your OS at boot up.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to install a boot loader manually.  When you run the Ubuntu installation, choose to install it along side Windows and you should be fine.